# How to align a TableLayout to the bottom of another TableLayout?

Tags: android, xml, button

I am trying to achieve a "phone dialer" look, but can't seem to get it to work. Here's the code that i have:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="splitzerjoke.zickens.com.calcuhorario.nuevoHorario"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" >

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nuevoHorario_lunes"
        android:text="@string/nuevoHorario_lunes"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#999999"
        />
    <!-- Éstas son las filas para seleccionar las horas ocupadas -->

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora1_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora1_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora2_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora2_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora3_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora3_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora4_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora4_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora5_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora5_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora6_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora6_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora7_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora7_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora8_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora8_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora9_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora9_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora10_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora10_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora11_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora11_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/hora12_lunes_texto"
            android:id="@+id/hora12_lunes"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/siguiente_lunes"
                android:text="@string/siguiente_lunes_texto"
                />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

And the preview looks like this:
[Preview](http://i58.tinypic.com/2yo69tu.png)

What i want to do is drag all those blue buttons down, so that the button that says "¡Listo!" touches the bottom, and all the other ones follow it; it's getting really frustrating to achieve this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have faced many problems with TableLayout like drawing/recreating views etc.  Use RelativeLayout instead. Its fast and relational.

Comment: Why did you take root layout as a table layout. why don't you use Relative or linear layout??

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout as your root layout and in your TableLayout do: android:alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: @zkminusck thank you! worked like a charm.

Comment: @zicken I placed an answer than ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` as your root layout and in your `TableLayout` do: `android:alignParentBottom="true"`